# Google Drive SDK and Server Side File Copy

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am building an application in PHP.  One goal of my application is to systematically move files from my web server to Google Drive.  I have so far found Google Drive API documentation a little confusing.  Before I spend too much time perusing this, I would like to ask the Stack Overflow community if it is even *possible* to copy files between my server and Google Drive, without a user authorizing each transaction?  I hope this question is not too vague.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Yes it's possible. Request offline access when you authorize and store the resulting Refresh Token